# Listen for new urls of ads posted to site

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
for (var i = 3848450; i > 3848400; i--) {
    var query = {
        url: 'http://classifieds.rennug.com/classifieds/viewad.cgi?adindex=' + i,
        type: 'html',
        selector: 'tr',
        extract: 'text'
    }

    ,
        uriQuery = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(query)),
        request  = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888//?q=' +
        uriQuery + '&callback=?';
    jQuery.getJSON(request, function (data) {
        var datastring = data[0].results;
        var datasplit = datastring.toString().split('Sign');
        $('#inner-content').append(datasplit[0]);
    });

}
```

I want to listen for new URLs of ads that are posted without writing some kind of arbitrary code that takes up a lot of memory looping through new URLs, etc. I can do that but it seems redundant and such as my code listed above. Im using noodle.js to get the info from the pages. Now I would like a way to listen for new urls instead of looping through every possible url from a to z. Since I don't know z it's a safe bet I'll be using an if statement but how would one go about incorporating this nth URL without ending up with undefined iterations. Im still learning and find this place has many helpful people. This is simply a fun project I'm doing to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correcly, you want an external thing to inform your javascript when there's new a `URL` or `JSON` data

Unfortunately the web is not built for servers to contact clients, with one exception to my knowleadge: `WebSocket`s

You already seem to have a local server so you meet the requirements plus node ships with them ready for use (also available on the browser). To use noodlejs with websockets you'd have to **require** the package and set up the `WebSocket` to send data to your client

Other than pointing you towards that direction, I don't think I can do better than the internet at giving you a tutorial. Hope this helps, Have fun! Also thanks for telling me about noodle, that thing is awesome!

Comment: Only problem is I don't own the server Im listening to. In that case maybe ill assume Im at the limit for this technology that may require the redundant work around.  Thanks

Comment: I assumed you did own the server since you mentioned it was a project for fun. What do you mean you don't own the server exactly? You can write code using noodlejs by requiring it's module (and you must if you want to persue this path) as I addressed in my answer, it's on the noodlejs overview page too. You can also check the reference on how to use it. Comment if you need more help on this

Comment: I should have been more specific. I don't own the server that Im targeting with this program.

Comment: Oh, you are right, it would involve moving the code you're trying to avoid to your server